# Does AtomicInteger really produce atomic integer?

Tags: java, thread-safety, sequences, atomicinteger

I googled for AtomicInteger and I saw someone said we can use AtomicInteger(AtomicLong) for memory sequencer (http://www.cs.hut.fi/u/tlilja/multicore/slides/java_multicore.pdf). Here is my test:

```
public class TestAtomicInteger {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final AtomicInteger sequencer = new AtomicInteger(1);
    final Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<>();
    //final Set<Integer> integers = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();


    final Runnable task = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int next = sequencer.getAndIncrement();
            integers.add(next);
            System.out.println(integers.size());
        }
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(task);
        t.start();
    }
}
}
```

After run this code for many times I found that sometime total of atomic output is not 1000. It means there is **DUPLICATE** return of **getAndIncrement** method.

Anyone explain why? Thanks.

**NOTE: In run function. If I use System.out.println(next); Sometime I see some missing sequencers too. **

**SAMPLE OUTPUT 1:**

1
6
8
5
2
10
3
4
12
11
9
14
15
7
13
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
42
41
43
45
44
47
49
46
48
52
52
50
53
55
54
58
56
57
59
60
61
62
63
64
65
67
68
69
66
70
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
80
81
79
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
97
96
98
99
104
103
106
102
109
100
101
108
107
111
105
112
114
110
117
116
119
115
120
113
118
121
122
126
125
124
123
127
128
130
131
129
132
133
134
135
136
137
138
139
140
141
142
144
145
143
146
147
148
149
150
151
152
153
154
155
156
157
158
159
160
161
162
163
164
165
166
167
168
170
169
171
172
173
174
175
176
177
178
179
180
181
182
186
188
189
185
190
184
191
192
183
187
193
194
196
197
198
199
195
200
201
202
203
204
205
206
207
208
209
210
211
212
213
214
216
217
219
215
218
220
232
231
230
229
228
227
226
225
224
223
221
222
233
234
235
237
239
240
236
238
241
243
242
245
244
246
247
248
249
250
251
252
253
254
255
256
257
258
259
260
261
262
263
264
265
266
267
268
269
270
271
272
273
274
275
276
277
278
279
280
281
282
285
284
283
289
288
287
286
292
291
293
294
290
295
296
297
298
299
300
301
302
303
304
305
306
307
308
309
310
311
312
313
314
315
316
317
318
320
321
319
322
323
324
325
326
327
328
330
329
331
332
333
334
335
337
336
338
339
340
341
343
344
345
346
347
348
342
349
350
351
352
353
354
355
356
357
358
359
360
361
362
363
366
365
364
368
367
369
370
371
372
373
375
374
379
378
377
376
380
381
382
383
384
385
386
389
388
387
392
394
395
391
397
390
399
398
400
396
393
403
404
402
401
406
405
407
408
409
410
411
412
413
414
415
416
417
419
418
420
421
423
422
424
425
426
427
429
430
428
434
433
435
432
431
436
437
440
439
445
446
447
438
458
459
460
457
456
462
463
464
455
454
453
470
452
473
475
451
450
477
479
480
449
482
448
444
442
509
443
441
511
510
508
507
506
515
516
518
519
520
505
504
522
503
502
525
532
501
500
499
498
497
496
495
535
494
493
538
492
491
490
541
543
489
546
488
548
549
487
486
485
484
550
552
483
481
478
556
557
476
558
474
472
471
469
468
567
467
569
570
466
465
461
574
573
575
576
572
571
568
566
565
564
563
562
561
560
559
555
554
553
551
547
545
544
540
578
585
542
539
537
536
595
534
597
533
531
599
530
529
528
600
602
527
526
604
524
523
521
608
519
517
514
513
614
512
613
612
616
617
611
610
619
609
621
607
606
622
623
605
603
601
598
625
627
596
594
631
593
592
632
633
591
590
638
589
588
587
640
641
586
584
583
582
648
651
653
655
657
581
658
659
662
664
580
668
579
669
577
667
666
672
665
673
674
675
663
661
676
677
680
683
685
687
689
661
660
656
654
692
652
650
649
646
647
703
645
644
643
642
639
637
636
635
634
630
713
629
628
626
715
624
717
620
720
722
618
615
721
723
719
718
716
714
712
711
710
709
708
728
729
707
706
705
704
702
701
700
699
698
697
696
695
694
693
691
690
688
686
684
730
731
732
733
682
681
679
678
671
670
734
735
727
739
726
725
724
738
740
742
737
744
745
736
746
747
743
741
749
748
751
750
753
752
754
755
756
757
758
759
760
761
762
763
765
764
770
771
772
773
774
769
768
776
767
780
766
779
778
777
775
784
783
782
781
787
788
790
791
792
796
786
798
799
800
785
803
805
807
802
801
797
795
794
793
812
789
813
811
816
810
809
808
806
819
821
823
824
826
827
828
830
831
832
839
840
842
843
844
846
847
848
849
850
851
853
855
804
856
854
852
858
848
860
861
845
841
838
837
836
835
834
864
865
833
829
825
822
868
869
820
818
871
817
874
875
815
814
876
877
878
879
880
881
882
883
885
887
888
889
891
892
894
896
898
901
902
903
905
906
875
873
872
870
867
866
863
862
859
857
904
900
899
897
895
893
907
890
908
886
884
909
910
911
912
913
914
927
928
926
929
931
932
934
938
939
940
942
925
944
945
924
923
922
948
921
949
920
919
918
915
916
917
951
950
947
946
943
941
937
936
935
952
953
933
930
954
955
956
957
958
959
960
961
962
963
964
965
966
968
969
970
971
972
985
986
987
967
989
988
990
985
984
991
983
982
993
981
980
979
978
977
976
975
974
973
995
995
992

Comment: Can you should such output that doesn't contain 1000?

Comment: Creating 1000 threads in a tight loop might be seriously stressing the JVM. It's much more likely that a thread either didn't finish or you missed something in the output than that `AtomicInteger` not working properly.

Comment: We can see 1000 in your output.

Comment: It seems far more likely that it is System.out.println on your platform that doesn't like 1,000 threads all trying to use it at the same time, than there is a huge bug in the java memory model that no one has found until now... have you tried accumulating the results in a thread-safe collection and then printing them synchronously?

Comment: @ZouZou: Please see my update. It happens sometime.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: Can you see my last update?

Comment: Your code as posted is flawed. You need to use a synchronized set to safely modify it from multiple threads. You also need to wait for all threads to finish before testing the contents of the set. To design a proper test, take a look at using an executor service where you can wait for all threads to finish.

Comment: Please DO NOT edit the code in the question like this - you have changed the nature of the question by commenting out one line.

Comment: @Robin Green. I updated it back to original question. Sorry everyone. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One major issue with your code is that you add the numbers to a `HashSet` which is not thread safe. That is the reason for what you are observing. If you used a thread safe collection, you would get the expected result:

```
final Set<Integer> integers = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<>();
```

But that introduces an additional layer of synchronization. Another alternative is to use a plain array `int[] numbers = new int[1000];` and use: `numbers[next-1]++;` to count the occurences.

New code for reference:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final AtomicInteger sequencer = new AtomicInteger(1);
    final int[] integers = new int[1000];

    final Runnable task = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int next = sequencer.getAndIncrement();
            integers[next-1]++;
        }
    };
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(task);
        t.start();
        threads.add(t);
    }
    for (Thread t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        if (integers[i] != 1) System.out.println(i + " -> " + integers[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used ConcurrentSkipListSet and re-test. I had the same issue. ( Sometime).

Comment: @Loc - Are you ensuring that all threads finish before testing the result (the way assylias does in the second loop)?

Comment: @Loc A `HashSet` (or rather the `HashMap` that supports it) starts at a default size of 16 and doubles in size when needed. So 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, etc. The 1000 must be getting lost in the resizing.

Answer (score 2):

If I run your program on my computer, I observe incorrect output about 1 in 10 times.  (This is with the console emulator in Netbeans 7.)

However, if I modify it to check the size of the set after all threads are complete, it always contains 1,000 unique integers.  This is true even when there are errors in the output generated by the individual threads while it is running.  (That is, in the lines printed by the threads, there are duplicates printed, but the true size of the set after execution is complete is actually 1,000)

Therefore I conclude that the problem is having 1,000 threads all writing to the PrintStream that your platform provides for System.out is corrupting the output.  On my platform I can see corrupted output during execution, but there are always 1,000 unique integers in the set at the end.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    final AtomicInteger sequencer = new AtomicInteger(1);
    final Set<Integer> integers = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Integer>();

    final Runnable task = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            int next = sequencer.getAndIncrement();
            integers.add(next);
            System.out.println(next);
        }
    };
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>(1000);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Thread t = new Thread(task);
        t.start();
        threads.add(t);
    }

    for (Thread t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
    System.out.println(integers.size());
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I re-checked the size of the integers set after all the threads have completed and verified it has 1,000 unique integers in it, to support my assertion is that the problem is the PrintStream implementation set to System.out is not handling 1,000 threads writing it concurrently and getting corrupted.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis  re-worded it to try to say that more clearly :)

Comment: Yep, that too. Printing needs to be done inside a "synchronized" method. Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

AtomicInteger makes calls to the Unsafe class, which in turn makes native calls. So yes AtomicInteger may theoretically return non atomic updates. This would depend on the JVM and and the underlying architecture it is running.

However given the nature of threads I would always assume the bug is in my code not the JVM.

I ran this code and was unable to detect any collisions. JDK 1_7_45 win 7

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

      final AtomicInteger sequencer = new AtomicInteger(1);
      final Set<Integer> integers = new HashSet<Integer>();

      final Runnable task = new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
              int next = sequencer.getAndIncrement();
              synchronized (integers){
                  if(integers.contains(next)){
                      System.out.println("duplicate detected " + next);
                  }
                  integers.add(next);
              }
          }
      };


      for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j++){
          System.out.print("testing " + j +" ");
          sequencer.set(0);
          integers.clear();
          List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>(10000);
          for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
              Thread t = new Thread(task);
              threads.add(t);
              t.start();
          }
          for (Thread t : threads) {
              try {
                  t.join();
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
          }
          System.out.println("integers size " + integers.size());
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said:

1. Wait for all threads to finish at the end of the end of the loop using [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29). References to all the Threads must have been stored in a Collection of course
2. close() STDOUT before exiting

Around the program:

1. Pipe the output through `sort` and/or `wc -l`
2. Use `diff` to check against a list of numbers created by a simple loop
3. Exit with warning if diff finds a difference

Repeat 10'000 times in a scripted loop.

Report back.

Comment: I re-updated my code and I tested 1000 threads. It produced wrong output as I said. ( Rarely happen)

Comment: @Loc - You aren't waiting for all threads to finish. That is critical to a proper test.

Answer (score 0):

The updated output contains 7 ints printed twice.

(took your output | sort | uniq --count | sort )

prints this at the end (first col is number of times seen, 2nd col is the value)

```
  1 991
  1 992
  1 993
  2 519
  2 52
  2 661
  2 848
  2 875
  2 985
  2 995
```

This is because you are printing the size of the HashSet which is not threadsafe so sometimes the size isn't showing the updated value.

Changing to a threadsafe Set implementation should work.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it's because of ConcurrentSkipListSet.size(). This kind of weakly consistent collection although thread-safe are not precise on iterations or counting in general.

From Javadoc of ConcurrentSkipListSet.size()

> Beware that, unlike in most collections, the size method is not a constant-time operation. Because of the asynchronous nature of these sets, determining the current number of elements requires a traversal of the elements. Additionally, the bulk operations addAll, removeAll, retainAll, and containsAll are not guaranteed to be performed atomically. For example, an iterator operating concurrently with an addAll operation might view only some of the added elements.